# What redirection should I use whether I am not sure it is temporary or permanent?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, 302-redirect

I know that 301 redirection for permanent redirection. 302 for temporary redirects.

I want to redirect author pages to BuddyPress profile pages in WordPress.

I am not sure that it will be permanent. I might cancel redirection after one month, two month or may be after one year or may be redirection will be permanents. It depends on my future plan as well as what my website readers suggest.

So what redirection should I use whether I am not sure it is temporary or permanent?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", so are you asking primarily for search engines?   There are also browser cache issues to consider.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I thought only about SEO. I did not know about even relationship between browser cache and redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As you already know **301 is permanent** redirection and **302
  temporary** redirection.
- Now comparing  both of these 301 in most cases is important for
  indexing in search engines as their crawlers take this in account and
  transfer **Page rank when using 301**.
- However if your redirection is    for short period of time or you
  plan to reverse it in future the main    issue with 301 redirect is
  that browser will cache the redirection    even if you disabled the
  redirection from the server level. It is always better to use **302 redirect** if
  you are enabling the redirection for a    short period of time.

With that being said you want to experiment for sometime whether you like the results of redirection or not. In that case I would suggest going for **temporary redirect for the experimental time period (a couple of days)** and then change it to permanent redirect if you are happy with the results.

Comment: But I have heard that don't use 302 redirection for longer period. I have heard that use 302 redirection for just couple of days or maximum one month.  Related article on Moz : https://moz.com/community/q/how-long-is-it-safe-to-use-a-302-redirect

Comment: Yes obviously you should experiment for a week or at max a month and then decide whether you want to move forward with this kind of setup or not.

Comment: The problem is that, it is not enough time.One month is too short..... :-(